# Can I use historical films from Weimar/Nazi Germany for research? (Copyright UK law)

Tags: video

According to the UK's copyright law, can I use historical films from the Weimar Republic and Nazi Germany for a video collage?

Does anyone know any good place where I could find such films?

Answer (score 0):

Reach out to the [European Film Gateway](http://www.europeanfilmgateway.eu/about_efg/faq)'s FAQ and look for "May I use content found on the EFG for my own website or in other contexts?".

In addition to that you can ask for help in their [contact form](http://www.europeanfilmgateway.eu/about_efg/contact).